# Mongoose find a nested model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is an idea of what my mongodb document looks like (json format of course)

```
[
    {
        _id: 50, 
        team_name: 'bulls',
        players: [
            { 
                _id: 100, 
                player_name: 'Jokim'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So when the route `api/teams/50/players/100` hits I want to serve `Jokim`. I am trying to read other posts on mongoose nested documents, but I can't seem to find an answer for what I am looking for here. I simply want to find the document, I already have the route setup.

```
models.Team.find({'players._id':req.params.id }, function(err, player) {
    if (err) {
        res.json({error: 'player not found.'});
    } else {
        res.json(player);
    }
});
```

This is my SCHEMA

```
var Team = new Schema({
    team_name:   { type: String },
    players: [
        {
            player_name:  { type: String },
            points:       { type: Number },
            made_one:     { type: Number },
            made_two:     { type: Number },
            made_three:   { type: Number },
            missed_one:   { type: Number },
            missed_two:   { type: Number },
            missed_three: { type: Number },
            percentage:   { type: Number },
            assists:      { type: Number },
            rebounds:     { type: Number },
            steals:       { type: Number },
            blocks:       { type: Number },
            fouls:        { type: Number },  
            feed:         { type: String },
            facebook_id:  { type: Number }
        }
    ],
    points:       { type: Number },
    made_one:     { type: Number },
    made_two:     { type: Number },
    made_three:   { type: Number },
    missed_one:   { type: Number },
    missed_two:   { type: Number },
    missed_three: { type: Number },
    percentage:   { type: Number },
    assists:      { type: Number },
    rebounds:     { type: Number },
    steals:       { type: Number },
    blocks:       { type: Number },
    fouls:        { type: Number },  
    feed: { type: String }
});
```

Comment: Not really sure what you mean as there is no reason the query you are doing will not work. Do you expect to retrieve **only** the nested document?

Comment: Yeah I am trying to get the one specific model, the purpose of the route here is to getByID

Comment: The route needs to get the team, then get the player. So its a collection within a collection... `api/teams/:id/players/:id` then I would use the `req.params.id` as the wildcard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you query `Team`, the docs that are returned by Mongoose have the same structure as your schema, so you need to pull out the player you're looking for from that structure.

Use the [`$` positional projection operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) to identify the first player matched in your query so that your result only contains that player in the `players` array field:

```
models.Team.findOne(
    {'players._id': req.params.id }, 
    {'players.$': 1}, 
    function(err, team) {
        if (err || !team || !team.players || !team.players.length) {
            res.json({error: 'player not found.'});
        } else {
            res.json(team.players[0]);
        }
    }
);
```

Note that `findOne` is used instead of `find` because you're only looking to find the single team containing that player.

Comment: I found a way I used this `{ _id: req.params.teamid }, { players: { $elemMatch: { _id: req.params.playerid } } }` and then in the res.json I used `res.json(player[0].players);` do you think they do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

So probably the approach you are looking for uses the [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/aggregate/) method. Of course you are going to extract your `team_id` and `player_id` values from your route:

```
models.Team.aggregate(
    [
        // Makes sense to match the document
        { "$match": { 
            "_id": team_id,
            "players._id": player_id
        }},

        // Unwind the players array
        { "$unwind": "$players" },

        // Match the player only
        { "$match": { "players._id": player_id } },

        // Just project the player
        { "$project": { "_id": 0, "player": "$players" } }
    ],
    function(err,docs) {

       // do work here
    }
);
```

So while positional projection would allow you to project a single array element that was matching as part of the parent document, the projection form in the aggregation pipeline allows you to completely re-shape to just contain the matching array element in the response.

For further information on aggregation, see the [operator reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) in the manual.

But for a basic example with the document you present:

```
db.teams.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "_id": 50,
        "players._id": 100
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$players" },
    { "$match": { "players._id": 100 } },
    { "$project": { "_id": 0, "player": "$players" } }
])
```

Gives the result:

```
{ "player" : { "_id" : 100, "player_name" : "Jokim" } }
```

Comment: Wow this is new :) okay let me wrap my head around this

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry What exactly can you not get to work? Your schema is embedded as you show in your question is it not?

Comment: I just feel like there is an easier way `models.Team.find({ 'players.player_name': 'Jokim' }` this returns all the players... thanks for the effort but I am going to keep fiddling with it untill I figure it out...

Comment: Let me try your solution again maybe my route was messed up

Comment: I just get an empty array when I `res.json(docs)`I am passing static ids for now until I get to appropriate json response

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry You must be doing something wrong. See the direct shell example added to the answer.

Comment: yeah funny beacuse I was just messing around with that syntax... here is the route `http://localhost:4300/api/teams/5362dcf7e99615aa392d7d72/player/5362dcf7e99615aa392d7d72`

Comment: Here is my code for that route... `router.get('/api/teams/:id/player/:id', player.getById);`

Comment: Then in my controller `getById` I search for the model like this `{ players: {_id: '5365f079ed4914600d9342c7', player_name: "Jokim"} }` and keep getting an empty array, I am trying to think... I am pretty burned out lol

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry You have two params named `:id` change them to be specific like I gave you originally

Comment: Oh yeah i was thinking about that earlier like `:playerid` but right now im passing static ids, they do match the mongodb ids though...

Comment: Maybe the id needs to be ObjectId() when passing statically instead of just the id

Comment: I don't understand why this wouldnt work `{_id: '5362dcf7e99615aa392d7d72', players: {player_name: "Jokim"} }`

Comment: I am playing around with `{"players":{"$elemMatch":{"$in":"player_name"}} }` this seems to be getting closer, there is something I need to slightly fix I think