# Mongo db - Querying a nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am really struggling with building a REST api with the data I have below, everything works fine on the client side  but when I need to make POST requests to update `players` I cannot figure out how to query mongodb.

**The route**

```
router.get('/api/teams/:teamid/player/:playerid', player.getById);
```

**The mongodb query**

```
module.exports = {
    getById: function(req, res) {
        models.Team.findOne({"players.player_name":"Jokim"}, function(err, player) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({error: 'player not found.'});
            } else {
                console.log(player);
                res.json(player);    
            }
        });
    }
};
```

**The Json data**

```
[
   {
      "__v":0,
      "_id":"5362dcf7e99615aa392d7d72",
      "assists":80,
      "blocks":14,
      "feed":null,
      "fouls":20,
      "made_one":10,
      "made_three":5,
      "made_two":15,
      "missed_one":4,
      "missed_three":4,
      "missed_two":20,
      "percentage":50,
      "points":44,
      "rebounds":100,
      "steals":33,
      "team_name":"Bulls",
      "players":[
         {
            "player_name":"Jokim",
            "_id":"5365f079ed4914600d9342c7",
            "team_name":"",
            "team_id":"",
            "points":0,
            "made_one":0,
            "made_two":0,
            "made_three":0,
            "missed_one":0,
            "missed_two":0,
            "missed_three":0,
            "percentage":0,
            "assists":0,
            "rebounds":0,
            "steals":0,
            "blocks":0,
            "fouls":0,
            "feed":""
         },
         {
            "player_name":"Taj",
            "_id":"5365f079ed4914600d9342c6",
            "team_name":"",
            "team_id":"",
            "points":0,
            "made_one":0,
            "made_two":0,
            "made_three":0,
            "missed_one":0,
            "missed_two":0,
            "missed_three":0,
            "percentage":0,
            "assists":0,
            "rebounds":0,
            "steals":0,
            "blocks":0,
            "fouls":0,
            "feed":""
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "team_name":"Wizards",
      "points":44,
      "made_one":10,
      "made_two":15,
      "made_three":5,
      "missed_one":4,
      "missed_two":20,
      "missed_three":4,
      "percentage":50,
      "assists":80,
      "rebounds":100,
      "steals":33,
      "blocks":14,
      "fouls":20,
      "feed":null,
      "_id":"5362dcf7e99615aa392d7d75",
      "__v":0,
      "players":[
         {
            "player_name":"John Wall",
            "points":22,
            "made_one":3,
            "made_two":4,
            "made_three":5,
            "missed_one":2,
            "missed_two":3,
            "missed_three":4,
            "percentage":5,
            "assists":2,
            "rebounds":2,
            "steals":2,
            "blocks":5,
            "fouls":3,
            "feed":null,
            "facebook_id":null,
            "_id":"5362dcf7e99615aa392d7d77"
         },
         {
            "player_name":"Bradley Beal",
            "points":22,
            "made_one":3,
            "made_two":4,
            "made_three":5,
            "missed_one":2,
            "missed_two":3,
            "missed_three":4,
            "percentage":5,
            "assists":2,
            "rebounds":2,
            "steals":2,
            "blocks":5,
            "fouls":3,
            "feed":null,
            "facebook_id":null,
            "_id":"5362dcf7e99615aa392d7d76"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: What is the problem? Any error?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What action do you want to do? I suppose you want to create a new 'player' subdocument since you are creating a rest api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are trying to search within players array I think you will have to use elemMatch:

Please find the docs related to the same: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

PS: I have not tried this as I do not have NodeJS with Mongo on my system now.

Comment: Yeah that sounds right.. I fiddled with many different ways I came across that, but it didnt do me any good I didnt use it properly most likely.. Let me read on that more, I 1+ because I think this is on the right track..

Comment: Here is the query `{ _id: "5362dcf7e99615aa392d7d72" }, { players: { $elemMatch: { player_name: "Jokim" } } }` worked like a charm :)

Comment: the only problem is the json is not pure, meaning its not the straight up object `{"_id":"5362dcf7e99615aa392d7d72","players":[{"player_name":"Jokim","_id":"5365f079ed4914600d9342c7","team_name":"","team_id":"","points":0,"made_one":0,"made_two":0,"made_three":0,"missed_one":0,"missed_two":0,"missed_three":0,"percentage":0,"assists":0,"rebounds":0,"steals":0,"blocks":0,"fouls":0,"feed":""}]}`

Comment: Seems like this is a good solution for that `res.json(player[0].players)`

Comment: Yeah could be but what happens if there are no records returned. It might throw an error as player[0] will not be present.

Comment: Ah good point I am guilty I opened another question and the answer was similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467726/mongoose-find-a-nested-model I think maybe using that or a mix of the two should have me set.

Answer (score -2):

Usually people are using `PUT` method to update model.
Check the [update](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#update) method in mongodb docs.

**Route**

```
router.put('/api/teams/:teamid/player/:playerid', player.updatePlayer);
```

**Controller**

```
module.exports = {
  updatePlayer: function(req, res) {
    models.Team.update({"players.player_name":"Jokim"}, {$set: {assist: 100}}, function(err, player) {
      if (err) {
        res.json({error: err});
      } else {
        console.log(player);
        res.json(player);    
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: When testing I dont want to have to run a POST every time I want to get a response