# MongoDB Aggregation: Value in Array

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, aggregation-framework

We have the following Testsnippet in Ruby

```ruby
def self.course_overview(course_member=nil)
  course_member = CourseMember.last if course_member == nil

  group_global = {"$group" =>
    {"_id" => { "course_id" => "$course_id",
                "title" => "$title",
                "place" => "$place",
                "description" => "$description",
                "choosen_id" => "$choosen_id",
                "year" => {"$year" => "$created_at"},
                "course_member_ids" => "$course_member_ids"}}
  }

  match_global = {"$match" => {"_id.course_member_ids" => {"$in" => "#{course_member.id}"} }}


  test = CoursePlan.collection.aggregate([group_global, match_global])

  return test
end
```

The problem is the "match_global" statement. We would like to match all Documents where the course_member ID is appearing in the course_member_ids array.

The above statement fails with the error: "...must be an array". This make sense to me but according to other comments on the web this should be possible this way.

Any advice? How is it possible to return the docs where the course_member id is in the array of the course_member ids?

Sample CoursePlan Object:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5371e70651a53ed5ad000055"),
    "course_id" : ObjectId("5371e2e051a53ed5ad000039"),
    "course_member_ids" : [ 
        ObjectId("5371e2a751a53ed5ad00002d"), 
        ObjectId("5371e2b251a53ed5ad000030"), 
        ObjectId("5371e2bb51a53ed5ad000033")
    ],
    "created_at" : ISODate("2014-05-13T09:33:58.042Z"),
    "current_user" : "51b473bf6986aee9c0000002",
    "description" : "Schulung 1 / Elektro",
    "fill_out" : ISODate("2014-04-30T22:00:00.000Z"),
    "place" : "TEST",
    "title" : "Schulung 1",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-05-13T09:33:58.811Z"),
    "user_ids" : [ 
        ObjectId("51b473bf6986aee9c0000002"), 
        ObjectId("521d7f606986ae4826000002"), 
        ObjectId("521d8b3f6986aed678000007")
    ]
}
```

Comment: Not sure but I think you are looking for elemMatch. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469463/mongo-db-querying-a-nested-array-of-objects/23469748#23469748

Comment: How can we use elemMatch on a "flat" array like ["123", "234"]? Because, i think, elemMatch needs a object like [{val: "123"}, {val: "234"}].

Comment: Kind of a little hard given you have not presented any sample data. But the general premise is correct even though the array is "anonymous" for key values. So how about some relevant data?

Comment: what is the course_member_ids in the original documents?  If it's an array of course member ids then just test for equality. {$match:{"_id.course_member_ids":<valueYouWantToTest>}} in shell terms.  You don't need $in.

Comment: You're right, i've added a sample object. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Asya, your answer is correct. There is no need for $in or $elemMatch. If the value is converted to an ObjectId it's working fine.
Working example: {$match:{"_id.course_member_ids": ObjectId:("123")}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `course_member_ids` is an array of course members you should test for equality. In shell syntax:

```
{$match:{"_id.course_member_ids":<valueYouWantToTest>}}
```

You don't need `$in` as this query is analogous to a `find` when you want to select documents that have a particular single value you are looking for.